# php: concatenate str var and str literal as key for a POST value

Tags: php, concatenation

Having trouble with this. I want to reference the post superglobal using a key which is generated by the concatenation of a string literal and a string variable.

```
$guests = array();
$guest_data = $this->compile_guests_for_hcp('g1');
array_push($guests, $guest_data($hcp_id));

function compile_guests_for_hcp($guest_identfier){
    return function($hcp_id) use ($guest_identfier){
        $guest = array(
            'fname' => $_POST["fname_$guest_identifier"],
            'lname' => $_POST["lname_$guest_identifier"],
            'city' => $_POST["city_$guest_identifier"],
            'state' => $_POST["state_$guest_identifier"],
            'degree' => $_POST["degree_$guest_identifier"],
            'zip' => $_POST["zip_$guest_identifier"],
            'specialty' => $_POST["specialty_$guest_identifier"],
            'email' => $_POST["email_$guest_identifier"],
            'phone' => $_POST["pref_phone_$guest_identifier"],
            'job_title' => $_POST["job_title_$guest_identifier"],
            'office_addr_line_1' => $_POST["office_addr_line_1_$guest_identifier"],
            'office_addr_line_2' => $_POST["office_addr_line_2_$guest_identifier"],
            'hcp_data_idhcp_data' => $hcp_id
        );
        return $guest;
    };
}
```

PHP is throwing undefined variable errors as it's trying to reference for example `$_POST["fname_"]` and `$_POST["guest_identifier"]`

I'm trying to access $_POST["fname_g1"] etc.

Answer (score 2):

Second to testing if the variable is set using `isset()` before you try to access its value.  You can even be more direct in your syntax and write the string concatenation in:

```
$var = isset( $_POST[ 'fname_' . $guest_identifier]) ? 
           $_POST[ 'fname_' . $guest_identifier] : 'default_value'
```

Your post makes it sound like PHP is trying to access two separate variables, `$_POST["fname_"]` and $_POST["$guest_identifier"], which shouldn't be the case, especially with the above syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the operator like: `$_POST["fname_".$guest_identifier]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that your approach is a bit overly complicated, but your issue is not in the array index concatenation: there are no syntax errors in your code as you've presented it.

For example, this works like a charm:

```
$a = array("foo"=>1); 
$o = "o"; 
print $a["fo$o"]; // prints 1
```

Your issue is that the `$guest_identifier` value is not being set properly so you are looking for POST indexes which simply aren't there.

There are a few different ways around this. My first suggestion would be to simply verify that the ID is there to begin with before calling this function. If that is not an option, then I would probably create a helper:

```
function ifInPost($val, $default = NULL){
    if( isset( $_POST[ $val ] ) ) return $_POST[ $val ];
    return $default;
}
```

Then, you could simply replace the `$_POST["fname_$guest_identifier"]` with `ifInPost("fname_$guest_identifier")`

Comment: I can see in debugging, right before the $guest array is returned that $guest_identifier and $hcp_id are both correctly set. Also, I can see POST values I am trying to reference are all set., yet all th $guest array contains is the last entry, 'hcp_data_idhcp_data' => 100

Comment: What happens if you print out `$guest_identifier` the line immediately after `return function($hcp_id) use ($guest_identfier){`?

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!
(Facepalm)

Simple spelling error in my argument so it was not being passed. I had identfier. Missing the i. I should pay more attention to the browser spellcheck when posting code hahaha!

```
function compile_guests_for_hcp($guest_identfier){
return function($hcp_id) use ($guest_identfier){
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you in making dynamic insertion of `n` number of product.

```
$loopLength=$_POST['ProudctSize'];

for ($i=1; $i <=$loopLength; $i++) 
{
    $productid=$_POST['P'.$i];
    $quatity=$_POST['Q'.$i];
    $rate=$_POST['R'.$i];

   $Insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO saledisplay ( `saleid`, `productid`, `quantity`, `rate`) 
                    VALUES('$oid','$productid','$quatity','$rate')");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace all calls to `$_POST[...` with `@$_POST[...` to repress the errors.

Or check the value before using it like `isset($_POST[...]) ? $_POST[...]` ...

Or suppress PHP warnings by calling [error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: My problem is that I want to access $_POST["fname_g1"], by concatenating the "fname_" part with (str)$guest_identifier which is equal to "g1"